# Enable hyphenation only for chemmacros

Tags: hyphenation, chemmacros, chemformula

I am writing my thesis with XeLaTex. Since hyphenation is uncommon/discouraged in our theses I switched it off by using the `hyphenat` package. Unfortunately, this also prevents line breaks in very long chemical names. I also have a lot very long chemical formulas which sometimes have to be hyphenated, e.g. in headings and tables.

Is there a way to disallow hyphenation for normal text and at the same time allow hyphenation for commands of the `chemmacros` and `chemformula` packages? My aim is to define commands for long names and formulas in the preamble so that XeLaTex knows how to break them in headings, TOC, captions etc. Otherwise I would have to break them manually everytime.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
     headsepline,
     footsepline,
     twoside,       
     numbers=noenddot,
     12 pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Cambria}
\usepackage{polyglossia}    
\setmainlanguage[spelling=new]{german}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}%
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{language = german,
     formula = chemformula,     
     greek = textgreek,
     modules = all,
     }
\NewChemCompoundProperty{|}{\-}% discretionary hyphens in chemformula

\begin{document}
\sloppy

These are filling words for a sentence with the very long word Antibiotikaresistenzentwicklung which I don't want to hyphenate.

This is a long chemical name \iupac{Tetra|cyclo[2.2.2.1^{1,4}]|undekan-2-dodekyl-5\-(hepta|dekyl|iso|dodekyl|thio|ester)} which I would like to break over several lines at one of the marked positions.

This is another sentence with the long chemical formula \ch{Cu(NCMe)2|(pyz)|[AuCl2(CN)2]2|UO2(NO3)2} which I would also like to break at one of the marked positions.

\end{document}
```

Since the `hyphenate` package changes `\hyphenpenalty` and `\exhyphenpenalty`, I also played with these and some other values.

```
\tolerance=9999
\hyphenpenalty=9000
\exhyphenpenalty=9999
\hbadness=10000
\emergencystretch=\maxdimen
```

I used them instead of `hyphenate` package and `\sloppy` and tried different values from 1-10000. But I only managed to globally disallow or allow hyphenation. I would not mind a few breaks but only for very long words and only to my conditions like e.g. Antibiotika-resistenz-entwicklung. So I added this (I tried with varying number from 4-75):

```
\righthyphenmin=75
\lefthyphenmin=75
```

This should be the letters before and after a break, right? But however, it has no effect and I still get line breaks after only two letters and in very short words. I also tried `\hyphenation{Antibiotika-resistenz-entwicklung}`. But that didn't work either. And to be honest, I am discouraged to use this option because that would mean I had to enter a lot of words manually.
So what am I doing wrong? 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, nobody replied and I haven't found a solution of this issue for `polyglossia` yet. But, however, I was able to solve the problem with the `hyphsubst package`. Hence, I switched from `polyglossia` to `babel`. So if anyone is interessested in a solution, the following code works nicely and gives exactly the behavior I want.

```
\documentclass[%
   headsepline,
   footsepline,
   twoside,       
   numbers=noenddot,
   12 pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}%
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}
\makeatletter\chardef\l@nohyphenation=255 \makeatother
\usepackage[ngerman=nohyphenation]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{language = german,
   formula = chemformula,     
   greek = textgreek,
   modules = all,
}
\NewChemCompoundProperty{|}{\-}% discretionary hyphens in chemformula

\begin{document}
\sloppy

These are filling words for a sentence with the very long word Antibiotikaresistenzentwicklung which I don't want to hyphenate.

This is a long chemical name \iupac{Tetra|cyclo[2.2.2.1^{1,4}]|undekan-2-dodekyl-5\-(hepta|dekyl|iso|dodekyl|thio|ester)} which I would like to break over several lines at one of the marked positions.

This is another sentence with the long chemical formula \ch{Cu(NCMe)2|(pyz)|[AuCl2(CN)2]2|UO2(NO3)2} which I would also like to break at one of the marked positions.

\end{document}
```